# How to delete rows with same value in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am working in windows Forms and I am trying to delete rows, which has same value. Code is here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView2.Rows[i+1].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(null))
                    break;
                else
                {
                    if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() != dataGridView2.Rows[i + 1].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
                        continue;
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                        i = i - 1;
                    }
                }
            }
```

So first Column consists of Names and I want to delete rows with same names.
But I am getting following error on first "if" :

"Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Idea is that if I have no more rows than I have to finish working. If not than I have to compare string values of row with next row. If same than I am deleting first of them , otherweise continue.

Have anyone I idea how to solve this Error message ?

Comment: Why are you saying Rows[i+1] in the first if statement?

Comment: to check if next Row is null or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
dataGridView2.Rows[i+1].Cells[0].Value == null
```

instead of

```
dataGridView2.Rows[i+1].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(null)
```

if Value object is null, ToString() method will not return null value, it will throw an exception.